# Diplaying JSON multidimensional array

Tags: json

I have this JSON array, but I don't know how display it.

```
{
    "grupy": [{
        "id_grupa_parametrow": "1",
        "id_grupa_nadrzedna": "0",
        "nazwa_grupy": "1_1",
        "opis_grupy": "hdghgh",
        "kolejnosc": "1233"
    }]
}
```

I tried:

```
 result["grupy"].id_grupa_parametrow;
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to know is that `{}` means that it's an object and `[]` is an array. So `result` in an object which has `grupy` property - that's why you have to use a dot here - `result.grupy`.

`grupy` is an array to you should use `[0]` index - `result.grupy[0]`.

And so on...

This is the right way in this case:

```
result.grupy[0].id_grupa_parametrow;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [some online json editors](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) to find your data easily. Anyway, you have an array defined for `groupy` index. So, use numerical indexes first:

```
result["grupy"][0].id_grupa_parametrow;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result.grupy[0].id_grupa_parametrow;
```